# Get BoundField value in GridView RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I want to take `LangId` value in RowDataBound function. How to do this?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LangId" HeaderText="LangId" Visible="false" />

protected void grdList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // need LangId
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnDelete");
        imgBtn.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to do it. Maybe more.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LangId" HeaderText="LangId" Visible="false" />

protected void grdList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       string langId = e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Text; // one of the ways

       string langId2 = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "LangId").ToString(); // one of the other ways
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by this:

```
string str = e.Row.Cells[CloumnIndexOfYourBoundField].Text;
```

`ColumnIndexOfYourBoundField` means if your column is first column than its index is 0 and if its second than its 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The data object is available as `e.Row.DataItem` at that time. You just need to cast it as the appropriate type.

```
var myItem = (MyType)e.Row.DataItem;
// myItem.LangId now available
```

Answer (score 0):

.ASPX file:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LangId") %>' CommandName="DeleteLedger" ToolTip="Delete"
        ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/DefaultClient/images/Delete.png" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

.CS file:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dataRow = ( DataRowView ) e.Item.DataItem;
    string strLangId = dataRow["LangId"].ToString();
    DataTable dtData1 = 
    objAccountTypeBAL.ChkLedgerRelation(Convert.ToInt64(strLangId ), objSession.BranchId);

    if (dtData1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)item["Delete"].Controls[0];
        img.Visible = false;          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic type you can access the fields in your record:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    dynamic data = e.Row.DataItem;
    int LangId = data.LangId;
    // do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GrdEmplistFromAtt_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lbl_GrdCode = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblGrdCode");
}
}
```